# AWS ELBについて教えて下さい

Tags: amazon-elb

Qiitaを見たり参考書を買ったりしてるんですが理解できていません。

参考書にはELBは2つのインスタンスを1つにするハードディスクでいうRAIDみたいなモノと書かれています。

しかしQiitaには一つのインスタンスを選択すると書いてあります。

Qiitaのように一つのインスタンスでも分割できるということでしょうか？
VPCについてもよく分かっていませんが、VPCを増やしたからといって機能が向上するわけではありませんよね？つまりこの場合一つのインスタンスのHDDを2つに分割してRAIDするのでしょうか？

http://qiita.com/hiroshik1985/items/ffda3f2bdb71599783a3

> インスタンスの設定
>   どのインスタンスをこのELBにぶら下げるかを設定する。 前回設定したEC2インスタンスを選択する。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ELBはRAIDとはぜんぜん違いますがその参考書はなんという書籍ですか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まず、RAIDの話は忘れてください。基礎を知っていると納得できますが、似ているだけで異なるものなので、逆に理解が難しくなります。

次に、ロードバランサーとは何か？について、お調べ下さい。参考にある qiita にあるものは使い方でした。使い方よりも、それが何なのか？どう使うものなのか？の方が重要です。

[今さら聞けない「ロードバランサの基本」 (1) ロードバランサの基本的な役割についてあらためておさらい | マイナビニュース](http://news.mynavi.jp/series/load_balancer/001/)

[Elastic Load Balancing（クラウドネットワークのロードバランサー） | アマゾン ウェブ サービス（AWS 日本語）](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/elasticloadbalancing/)

色々メリットはありますが、ざっくり言うと、
1. 1台が壊れても2台(複数台)あれば、安心
2. 沢山のアクセスが来ても、2台(複数台)あれば応答が速い
のような感じです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

VPCはまた別の話ですので、VPCとは何か？を一度ご確認の上、疑問点を絞られると宜しいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

１つのインスタンスを分割するわけではないです、複数のインスタンスを作成してアクセスを各EC2に分散させるためのELBです。